# Is the MASQUERADE target terminating or non-terminating?

Tags: linux, iptables

Is the iptables' MASQUERADE a terminating or non-terminating target ?

Where is this officially documented ? The Netfilter's extensions [**man page**](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDE) does not mention it...

Comment: It's terminating. You can answer your own q by 1. adding a log rule just after it and see that it doesn't get hit and 2. look at its source code in the kernel and see that it can only return NF_DROP or NF_ACCEPT, not XT_CONTINUE.

Comment: They're probably only documenting when a target is non- terminating, since that's the exception. Besides, I don't see how MASQUERADE could be non-terminating. How could that work?

Comment: OK, guys - it's an answer...so please make it an answer so I can accept it and  others can benefit from this knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

All NAT rules are terminating. Matching 2 nat rule at same time would be nonsense. Note that, by terminating I mean packet will exit from NAT rules and continue to other tables.

In addition, when first packet match a rule in NAT chains, other packets from same connection also will not traverse NAT chains.

Comment: Firstly, it is impossible for the packet processed by the `MASQUERADE` target to "continue to other tables" because the `MASQUERADE` target MUST be in the `nat:POSTROUTING` chain and this is the LAST chain before the packet is transmitted by the outbound interface. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/niGU1.png

Comment: Secondly, processing a second rule - a rule AFTER the `MASQUERADE` target is processed, is not "nonsense" when one needs to e.g. to clone the output of the `MASQUERADE` target with a `TEE` for the purposes of monitoring / debugging the output of the outbound interface.  Sadly this is impossible because the `MASQUERADE` target is "terminating". See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553899/how-to-clone-the-output-of-the-masquerade-target-with-a-tee

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson I know MASQUERADE can only be used in POSTROUTING. I just generalized answer. If I clone packet with TEE it will create new packet an still it is nonsense to match 2 nat rule at same time for each packets.

Comment: The cloned packet will **not** be matched by the same rule in the `nat:POSTROUTING` chain, because the cloned packet is purposely marked to avoid just this scenario. Also, 2 rules in the `nat:POSTROUTING` chain having a TEE and the MASQUERADE targets (in that order!) make perfect sense if one wants to monitor the commencements of outbound connections on e.g. a dedicated host on the LAN running "Wireshark". Also, I still cannot agree that "packet will exit from NAT rules and continue to other tables" because no other tables exist after `nat:POSTROUTING` and that's where the MASQUERADE must be