# How to clone the output of the MASQUERADE target with a TEE?

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter

The Netfilter's extensions [**man page**](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDE) states that:

> MASQUERADE: This target is only valid in the `nat` table, in the `POSTROUTING` chain

QUESTION: How to clone the **output** of the `MASQUERADE` target with a `TEE` target ?

If you look at the diagram of `netfilter/iptables` below, you will notice that `nat.POSTROUTING` is the last chain to be evaluated before the packet is sent to the outbound interface.  There isn't a `raw.POSTROUTING` chain, ...or is there ?

[image]
Also see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553869/is-the-masquerade-target-terminating-or-non-terminating).

P.S.
What is the rationale for processing the `mangle` and `nat` tables in the same order at the `outbound` and `inbound` interface, when the data flows in **opposite directions** through these interfaces (egress and ingress) ?

Comment: afaik you can't do this with iptables. You should try with nftables because you can always change the priority of a chain's hook ( https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains#Base_chain_priority )

Comment: other method is [tc ... mirred egress mirror](https://manpages.debian.org/tc-mirred.8) because it happens after network, right at the interface layer. But something would have to alter the destination mac address for the intended target (which is what TEE is doing on its own with its gateway parameter).

Comment: @A.B.  And what do you think of modifying `.priority = NF_IP_PRI_NAT_SRC` to `.priority = NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK` in the code below ?: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.151/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.c#L85

Comment: tc mirred is too complex for this on 2nd thought (because of the unchanged mac address). There will be nftables

Comment: about the priority change, 1/ you wouldn't know what unforeseen side effects this would have (perhaps making firewalls fail etc.) 2/ you'd have to maintain for yourself a patched kernel forever : not good. You should invest time into nftables instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, since it's not possible to have an *iptables* rule executed after [*nat/POSTROUTING*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg), which is the last hook provided by *iptables*, it's not possible to use *iptables* to capture a packet post-NAT.

---

But this is possible when using [*nftables*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page), since the [hook priority is user defined](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains#Base_chain_priority). *nft*'s [*dup*](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#DUP_STATEMENT) statement is a direct replacement for *iptables*' *TEE*. It's possible to mix *nftables* and *iptables* as long as they're not both doing NAT (the nat ressource is special and can't be shared properly between *iptables* and *nftables*). Using [iptables-over-nftables](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/xtables-nft.8)'s version of *iptables* will also work (care should be taken when flushing rulesets), and of course using only *nft* for everything would also work.

Here's a ready made *nft* ruleset for this on a router with a NATed LAN on *eth1* and its WAN side on *eth2*, to send a copy to 192.168.0.3 in the LAN side. like described in an [other question from OP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553832/where-does-the-packet-cloned-by-iptables-mod-tee-go-after-cloning). To be put in some file named *forwireshark.nft* and to be "loaded" using `nft -f forwireshark.nft`:

```
table ip forwireshark {
        chain postnat {
                type filter hook postrouting priority 250; policy accept;
                oif eth2 counter dup to 192.168.0.3 device eth1
        }
}
```

What matters here is that the value 250 has been chosen to be higher than *iptables*' [`NF_IP_PRI_NAT_SRC` (100)](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains#Base_chain_priority).

Here's what would typically receive the wireshark host when the ping host does `ping -c1 8.8.8.8` after some inactivity (note the strange ARP request from the "wrong" IP, which might not be accepted by default on some systems):

```
root@ns-wireshark:~# tcpdump -e -n -s0 -p -i eth0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
21:06:03.074142 82:01:54:27:4d:d7 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.0.1 tell 192.168.0.2, length 28
21:06:03.074301 9a:80:fb:e6:6a:0a > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.0.3 tell 140.82.118.4, length 28
21:06:03.074343 7e:0a:6c:12:00:61 > 9a:80:fb:e6:6a:0a, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.0.3 is-at 7e:0a:6c:12:00:61, length 28
21:06:03.074387 9a:80:fb:e6:6a:0a > 7e:0a:6c:12:00:61, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 140.82.118.4 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1633, seq 1, length 64
```

---

I don't know the rationale on the order of *mangle/POSTROUTING* and *nat/POSTROUTING*. Anyway this is part of *iptables*' limitations, because in *nftables*, apart from the equivalent of *mangle/OUTPUT* which is a special [*type route*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains#Base_chain_types) hook for rerouting, all other equivalent usages of *mangle* are part of *type filter*: there's not really a separate *mangle* type anymore. Being able to choose the order of priorities allows to do more.

Comment: That is a good answer and a decent solution but i will not use it on current OpenWrt because other users want to continue using the LUCI front-end and switching to nftables would break it.  I will just patch the single `int` nat hook priority in the binary and be done with it (since the `mangle` table is unused).  When LUCI2 comes out with support for nftables, I will switch to your solution.  BTW: Do you know to what binary file the code below compiles to?  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.151/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.c#L85   I am too lazy to build entire Linux for 1 `int`.

Comment: No, I'm sure you'll figure it out